# Make webpage thinner for mobile client

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

Unfortunately mobile phones have such high screen resolutions that my website comes it far to small. It adapts perfectly when zoomed in on a desktop browser but unfortunately on mobile browser the webpage viewport size does not actually change once zoomed. To try and solve this I have already gotten a script that detects a mobile user agent and then sets the body width to 500px, this looks about the perfect width but unfortunately the mobile browser does not set its viewport to 500 even after I set the meta for viewport 500 and this results in my webpage rendering in the corner of the browser. Once zoomed in it looks fine though but that is not what I want. My site is in some way similar to nokia.com and I want it to behave in the same way on a mobile client.

Can someone please tell me what the correct procedure is for doing something like this because I am in no way a proper web developer, I am just doing this to learn.

Here is my meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it! It seems the reason I was having so much trouble is because the mobile device I was testing in was a Windows Phone 8 device and apparently WP8 does not really respond well to the viewport meta tag. This is easily solved by the addition of a MobileOptimized meta tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write conditional CSS rules for smaller browser sizes.

One example:
    `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .item1{}
    .item2{}
    }`

Here is a site I just found through a quick google search that should be able to get you started at least. http://www.conditional-css.com/usage

Good luck with your learning!

Comment: I am sorry but could you just elaborate what type of thing I should do differently in the mobile style sheet?

Comment: You are in essence making two sites.  If you go on a regular browser it will load the normal styles.  If you go on a mobile one have it load the mobile styles.  Here is another article to read: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `@media` queries (available is css3)

Something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) /* You can change this value per your requirements */ 
{
   /* Your custom styles for mobile device */
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but could you just elaborate what type of thing I should do differently in the mobile style sheet?

Comment: Use two queries, one for mobile device and other for desktop/tablets (`@media only screen and (min-device-width : 481px)`). Type in styles for these two conditions. In the mobile device condition you can do something like: `max-width: 480px;`, etc. You can change the background image. The possibilities are unlimited, it's all up to you. ;)

Comment: Yes I understand that but what things in css can I do differently on the mobile version, for example setting the body width to 500px has the effect where the viewport is still to small

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0 />
```

and use the media query to target all the screen size

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/thinking-ahead-css-device-adaptation-with-viewport

Hope this helps you

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't seem as if all browsers support this and it definitely does not work for me

Comment: I am totally at a loss with this media query thing but the addition of the scale parameters have all but fixed my problem, it now fills the screen properly except for the fact that it is now zoomed in to much by default and you have to zoom out. Is there any way to set the initial scale property for this.

Comment: @Gerhman Replace your meta tag with this one.

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0 />

This will scale the view to the default scale and take the content width of the device.

Hope this helps you

Comment: I am now using that tag but this is causing it to be zoomed in to much. I have tried running javascript on start-up which calculates how much larger the page is than the display width and then sets scale properties accordingly but unfortunately the browser does not want to respond to this meta being changed from of javascript.

Comment: Use media queries to style for the medium screen and small screen 

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/thinking-ahead-css-device-adaptation-with-viewport

Hope this helps you